# Some input nodes are larger than others and are overlapping with label nodes

Tags: html, css

I recently completed an HTML and CSS course on YouTube, so I decided to create a few projects to test my knowledge of these languages. I decided to create a form for a job application. The issue I am running into is that some of my input fields are larger than others. I have tried to resize the input fields with CSS, I have gone to Google and typed this "my input fields are larger than others" but the possible solutions don't help. If anyone can help I would appreciate the help. I also have labels next to the inputs as well. this is what I have so far. I will place the HTML code and the CSS code below. To further explain apart from my inputs being too larger when I declared it to be 100px, some of the inputs overlap with the label.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Application Form</title>
</head>
<body>
   <header></header>

    <form action="" class="index-form">
<h2 class="application">Please fill out the job application and we will contact you.</h2>


<section class="name">
    <label for="input-first" class="label-first">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-first" placeholder="First Name" required>
    <label for="input-last" class="label-last">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-last" placeholder="Last Name" required>
</section>

<section class="contact">
    <label for="input-contact" class="label-phone">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="number" class="input-phone" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
    <label for="input-email" class="label-email">E-mail</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-email" placeholder="E-mail" required>
</section>

<section class="location">
    <label for="" class="label-address">Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-address" placeholder="Address" required>
<label for="input-zip" class="label-zip">Zip Code</label>
<input type="number" class="input-zip" placeholder="Zip Code" required>
<label for="input-city" class="label-city">City</label>
<input type="text" class="input-city" placeholder="City"><br>
<label for="select-state" class="label-state">Choose your state</label>
<select class="select-state" required><br>
    <option value="none">Select state</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
    <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>   
</section>

<section class="position">
    <label for="input-position" class="label-position">Select position you are applying for?</label>
    <input type="radio" class="input-position" value="rbt" name="posiltion">RBT <br>
    <input type="radio" class="input-position" value="manager" name="posiltion">Manager <br>
    <input type="radio" class="input-position" value="bcba" name="posiltion">BCBA 
</section>

<section class="referance">
    <label for="input-referance" class="label-referance">How did you hear about us?</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="input-referance" value="flyer" name="flyer">Flyer <br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="input-referance" value="website" name="website">Website <br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="input-referance" value="friend" name="friend">Friend
</section>

<section class="finish">
    <label for="" class="label-finish">Please upload your resume and click the submit button.</label>
    <input type="file" class="input-upload"><br>
    
    <button class="submit">Submit</button> <br>
</section>
    </form>

</body>
</html>



/* IPhone 5/SE */
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    background-color: skyblue;
  }

  .index-form {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 300px;
    height: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  .index-form .application {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  }

  .index-form .name {
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .name .label-first,
  .label-last {
    display: none;
  }

  .name .input-first {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    /* for IE7*/
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .name .input-last {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline; /* for IE7*/

    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .index-form .contact {
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .contact .input-phone {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .contact .label-email,
  .label-phone {
    display: none;
  }

  .contact .input-email {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .index-form .location {
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .location .label-address {
    display: none;
  }

  .location .input-address {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    flex: 1;
  }

  .location .label-zip,
  .label-city,
  .label-address,
  .label-state {
    display: none;
  }

  .location .input-zip {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 2;
  }

  .location .input-city {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    flex: 3;
  }

  .location .select-state {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    flex: 4;
  }

  .index-form .position {
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .position .label-position {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-indent: -15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .position .input-position {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .index-form .referance {
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .referance .label-referance {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-indent: -15px;
  }

  .referancec .input-referance {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .index-form .finish {
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .finish .label-finish {
  }

  .finish .input-upload {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .finish .submit {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}

/* IPhone 5/SE */
@media only screen and (min-width: 568px) {
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    background-color: skyblue;
  }

  .index-form {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 534px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  .index-form .application {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  }

  .index-form .name {
    width: 534px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .name .label-first {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
  }

  .name .label-first:after {
    content: ":";
  }

  .name .label-last {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: 80px;
  }

  .name .label-last:after {
    content: ":";
  }

  .name .input-first {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    /* for IE7*/
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .name .input-last {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline; /* for IE7*/

    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .index-form .contact {
    width: 534px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .contact .input-phone {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .contact .label-email {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 80px;
  }

  .contact .label-email:after {
    content: ":";
  }

  .contact .label-phone {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 550px;
  }

  .contact .label-phone:after {
    content: ":";
  }

  .contact .input-email {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .index-form .location {
    width: 534px;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .location .label-address {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
  }

  .location .label-address:after {
    content: ":";
  }

  .location .label-zip {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
    left: -80px;
  }

  .location .label-zip:after {
    content: ":";
  }

  .location .label-city {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    right: 145px;
    position: relative;
  }

  .location .label-city:after {
    content: ":";
  }

  .location .input-address {
    position: relative;
    right: 90px;
  }

  .location .input-zip {
    position: relative;
    right: 10px;
    left: 380px;
    bottom: 25px;
  }

  .location .input-city {
    position: relative;
    right: 260px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .location .label-state {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
    right: -300px;
    bottom: 20px;
  }

  .location .label-state:after {
    content: ":";
  }

  .location .select-state {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 20px;
    width: 90px;
    flex-shrink: 3;
  }

  .location .select-state::first-line {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .index-form .position {
    width: 600px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .position .label-position {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-indent: -15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .position .input-position {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .index-form .referance {
    width: 700px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .referance .label-referance {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-indent: -15px;
  }

  .referancec .input-referance {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .index-form .finish {
    width: 400px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .finish .label-finish {
  }

  .finish .input-upload {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .finish .submit {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 568px) {
.location .select-state {
```

Remove

```
flex-shrink: 3;
```

Add

```
flex-grow: 0;
right: -146px;
```

But you should put the label and input/select inside a container and position that container instead.

```
<section class="name">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="input-first" class="label-first">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-first" placeholder="First Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="input-last" class="label-last">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="input-last" placeholder="Last Name" required>
    </div>
</section>
```

Also align the text and elements for a nice look.